# Which 11 countries were democratic in 1941?

Tags: democracy

Relistening to the BBC's History of Democracy broadcast in July 2011. The historian on the show talked about the low point for democracies being 1941 when there were ***just 11 parliamentary democracies remaining*** across the globe.

So, there was Britain and the US of course. Then there were the European neutrals, Ireland, Switzerland and Sweden. That's five. The commonwealth democracies: Canada, Australia and NZ. Let's add South Africa too (they had a parliament).

Maybe Finland (even though allied to the Nazis, possibly still
democratic?) Ten?

So, I only make that nine or ten. Which country or countries am I missing?

Comment: Was the US ever a parliamentary democracy?

Comment: Interesting question. The [democracy index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democracy_Index) lists 26 "full democracies" in 2010. If I see it correctly, all of those are either on your list (including Finland which was indeed a democracy) or were occupied or were not a democracy in 1941. Maybe they counted Iceland despite the British occupation?

Comment: This index is pretty absurd though, for example Greece, France, Italy, Israel, Slovakia, Poland, India, Hungary are "flawed democracies"

Comment: @Squark: I can't talk about the others, but Italy is definitely not better than flawed.

Comment: @Squark Did you read their criteria? I wouldn't say Poland is a perfect democracy, either.

Comment: @hawbsl You need to tell what is the broadcaster's prespective of democracy, prima facie, there seems to be more than 11 democracies even before 1941 based on purely technical considerations.

Comment: There were elected governments in some colonies as well during 1941, though their powers were probably severely limited. Example - India (first national election in 1933).

Comment: The source of the statement appears to be _The Life and Death of Democracy_ by John Keane ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Life_and_Death_of_Democracy)). I would suppose the book describes the criteria for election and the countries elected, but I have no access to the book. Can anyone help?

Comment: @Wilhelm - good find!

Comment: Perhaps Chile?...

Comment: By 41 Britain had DORA (Defence of the Realm Act) a coalition government and in effect a more totalitarian government than Nazi Germany. At that point a snapshot view would not indicate it was a democracy.

Comment: According to Wikipedia there were 12, not 11, democracies 1942 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_Wave_Democracy However, the source for that number (some US gov page) does not list which 12 countries. Anyone care to clarify? Is the OP or Wikipedia right?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://history.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://history.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: It is unclear if the OP or Wikipedia is right about the number. Then I can't request a clarification or critizise the question, just add details.

Comment: One could argue Switzerland should not be on the list, since women were not allowed to vote until the 70's.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since Samuel Huntington is quite popular in political science (which I guess the BBC derived its source from), I suspect that this group of 11 democracies is based on Huntington's thesis of [Third Wave Democracy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_Wave_Democracy).

According to Huntington, the globe experienced three waves of democracy, starting from USA in 1828. For this first wave, Huntington used Jonathan Sunshine's minimal qualification for democratic state: (1) 50 percent of adult males are eligible to vote; and (2) a responsible executive who either must maintain majority support in an elected parliament or is chosen in periodic popular elections.

At the peak of first wave democracy, there were 29 democratic states in the world. Then Italy rose to fascism in 1922, and the reversal of first wave democracy began.

The first wave had its worst year in 1942, where there were only a few states which remained democratic:

1. Finland
2. Iceland
3. Ireland
4. Sweden
5. Switzerland
6. United Kingdom
7. Australia
8. Canada
9. New Zealand
10. United States
11. Chile

You can read more about this on Huntington's *Third Wave Democracy*, or Roland Rich's introduction on his *[Pacific Asia in Quest of Democracy](https://www.rienner.com/uploads/47e29bb71ad1a.pdf)*.

Comment: Finland was a dictatorship.

Comment: @Anixx - [How so](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risto_Ryti#Prime_minister_and_president)?

Answer (score 10):

**Note: This is a partial and indicative list. I am looking for more information to improve it.**

**Update 2: It seems there is some controversy over the definition of democracy itself. Until further clarity it would be difficult to populate any such list.**

---

**[Parliamentary Democray](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parliamentary_republic#List_of_current_parliamentary_republics)**

- Switzerland (1802)
- Haiti (1860)
- Finland (1919)
- Turkey (1923)
- Ireland (1936)
- Lebanon (1941)

**That makes it - 6**

**[Presidential System of Democracy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presidential_system#Republics_with_a_presidential_system_of_government)**

- [USA (1776)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States)
- [Mexico (1917)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexico#Politics) (Thanks to @World Engineer)

**[Constitutional Monarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitutional_monarchy#List_of_current_reigning_monarchies)**

- UK (1688) (I am not sure of its inclusion, because if this is included then a significant region of western Europe may also be included so also Australia and New Zealand, which will take the number way beyond 11)
- [Canada (1867)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canada) Independence through British North American Act 1867.

**That makes it - 10**

Comment: Would Mexico count?

Comment: Weren't Estonia and Latvia part of the USSR by 1941?

Comment: @lins314159 Thanks! I am removing their inclusion for now, until I get further clarity. Also, here is the qualification on the link itself `The three Baltic states were parliamentary republics after declaring their independence from the Russian Empire in 1918, but were all occupied by the Soviet Union in 1940. After regaining independence by 1991, all three countries resumed to parliamentary democracy.`

Comment: @WorldEngineer Thanks! I have updated the list to include Mexico after checking up the references.

Comment: What about Peru? It has had a democratic constitution since 1933.

Comment: I'm curious about the date of 1936 for Ireland. The modern Irish constitution came into force in the last days of 1937, however the previous 'state', (the Irish Free State) had just as much voting rights as the 1937 constitution, that state came into being in 1922. However the Irish Free State didn't increase the voting right compared to when Ireland was in the UK.

Comment: 1688 for the UK is strange date (the Glorious Revolution), up until 100 years ago vast parts of the country could not vote at all (e.g. women (until 1918 (or 1930), people who didn't own land (1918), catholics (1829), etc.), as such it's a strange interpretation of "democracy" when only 1 out of 6 adult males could vote.

Comment: Lebanon was certainly not a democracy in 1941. Far from it. Like it's neighhbours it's was partially or wholly under martial law with a Vichy regime in charge and about to be attacked by Free French forces and the British. I am surprised it's on the list.

Comment: @ExpatEgghead That is precisely the issue. As Rory points out, there are difficulties in defining democracy and thus it now hinders upon the OP to clear his view of democracy.

Comment: The UK is both a constitutional monarchy and a parliamentary democracy, so I'm not convinced that placing it in its own category reflects how it is governed. It could be argued that it is more similar in its structure of government to, say, Ireland (prime minister as head of government, with a titular non-executive head of state) than Switzerland (ruling council which acts as both head of state and head of government).

Comment: @Rory: Not at all. Please do not confuse universal suffrage (which only appeared in any country during the last century) and democracy! The former is a subset of the latter.

Comment: How can you even question the inclusion of the UK? I don't see the relevance of it being a monarchy. It still is today, as are Australia, Canada, the Netherlands, Spain, Sweden, Denmark... as opposed to the republics of, say, Cuba, North Korea and China (PRC).

Comment: How can you question indeed! The United Kingdom (and its predecessor England) was the *first* **modern** democracy in the entire world! Don't forget the quote was from the BBC; highly unlikely to exclude the UK in such a list.

Comment: What about Canada? Canada is a Westminster Parliamentarian Democracy since 1 July 1867.

Comment: @txwikinger Canada didn't gain full control of its affairs until after WWI. The exact date is fuzzy, and a standard high school essay question, but as of WWI we did not have any control of foreign affairs, and thus were automatically drawn into the first world war. By WWII we had, and thus waited for a debate in our own parliament to occur before entering.

Comment: @Canageek that is not the question. Canada has been a federal parliamentary democracy and constitutional monarchy since July 1, 1867 according to its constitution

Comment: @txwikinger But it is questionable whether Canada was a country prior to gaining political independence. Either way, it should be on the list for the 1940s.

Comment: One reason they might not be including Canada, is that while we kept our normal government the term seems to have been extended; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/19th_Canadian_Parliament shows May 16, 1940 until April 16, 1945, which is over the normal 4 year term.

Comment: @Canageek With the same argument it could be said that neither West Germany (Federal Republic of Germany) before Oct 3, 1991, nor East Germany (German Democratic Republic) would have been countries, since they according of the Potsdam Agreement could not exist, and the full sovereignty had to be granted by the 4 allies at the re-unification agreements (4+2 talks). Nevertheless, both were members of the United Nations.

Comment: @txwikinger I was just trying to figure out why it was only 11, since if we have 12 now, but Australia has been around and democratic since 1901. It came to mind as one of the WWI themes a class I'm in is exploring is the interruptions of democracy during WWI- They might have considered similar situations in WWII.

Comment: You missed [Iceland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_of_Iceland#World_War_II_and_the_establishment_of_the_Republic). It was a constitutional monarchy whether you consider them in 1942 as part of Denmark or an independent nation. That would bring your list back up to 11.

Comment: @Noldorin *"! The United Kingdom (and its predecessor England) was the first modern democracy in the entire world!"* If you think England (before the Union, presumably) was democratic, then then we have to cede first place to Ancient Athens - excluding women, resident aliens and slaves, of course!

Comment: @TheHonRose Note the word *modern*. It was only highlighted in bold. :-P

Comment: @Noldorin It may have been "**modern**" (define modern?) but it certainly wasn't democratic! Athens, even with the caveats I mentioned, was arguably more democratic - Britain didn't achieve anything close to "one **man** one vote" until the early 20th Century.

Comment: @TheHonRose: Obviously, no modern system has achieved pure/direct democracy in the Athenian sense, because it's both impractical and highly flawed. But to say e.g. 18th or 19th century Britain wasn't democratic is misinformed to say the least. Lots of men living in Classical Athens did not have the right to vote or serve, remember (the huge number of slaves, principally). You do a great disservice to Britain and its role in forming modern democracy.

Comment: @Noldorin No, you specifically mention **England** (pre 18th Century, presumably) so do not see how my comments can do a "disservice" to Britain's slow move to democracy. Even in the 18th and 18th centuries, voting was based on **property** not citizenship, and notoriously corrupt. Even with the caveats I mentioned - women, metics and slaves - Athenian democracy was based on **citizenship** not, AFAIK, property. I am proud to be British, but not blind to her failures!  (NB Could a mod move this to Chat, we're straying from the question.)

Comment: @TheHonRose You started this conversation. ;-) Sure, there was property qualification, which was more or less a class distinction, but I don't see that as very different from Classical Athens. I also don't consider it any more corrupt than Athenian democracy (which had plenty of problems, and failed rather quickly and spectacularly, I must say!).

Comment: Why is not Sweden in that list? They were as democratic as UK 1941.

Answer (score 8):

Depends on how you define "democracy". Do you mean "one person, one vote" (universal adult suffrage)? Up until the early years of the 20th century women couldn't vote.

One could claim the USA didn't have full adult suffrage until after the Civil Rights Movement in the 1960s. Likewise South Africa wasn't exactly a paragon of "one person, one vote" until the end of apartheid.

If however you define "democracy" as "anything that's not fascist or communist", then the situation changes. (Victors writing the history books and all that)

Comment: Rory makes a good point. In that case I would argue that Iceland should have been on the list as a constitutional monarchy but in 1941 it was occupied by the British and then later by the USA. The date of 1941 does complicate matters. Why isn't Australia and New Zealand on this list?

Comment: Thinking about it more, I believe I could make a good case for the UK not being in the list as all normal democratic processes were suspended for the duration. Only by-elections were held, generally uncontested and the composition of the government did not change. As the whole of the UK was essentially under a benign marital law, I would suggest only the USA was a functioning democracy in 1941.

Comment: If you are including a country that was a democracy, but then invaded, then you have to include lots of countries that the Nazis invaded, such as France, countries in eastern & central Europe. Germany was a democracy until the Nazi Party were elected/took over, under this "used to be a decoracy" rule, does that mean Nazi Germany was a democracy in 1941‽

Comment: The UK just didn't have any elections for 10 years between 1935 and 1940. That is a long time, but the people who were there were elected in the first place. So it was more of a long running elected government. No massively democractic, but not really undemocratic either.

Comment: @Rory the UK has all powers in inherited office of king. Calling them "democracy" is like calling Russian Empire of 1913 "democracy" because they had an elected Duma.

Comment: @Anixx No, the UK Parliament had power and could and did depose the King.

Comment: @Rory only if they start a revolution ) Contrary, the king has all powers to dissolve parliament any time.

Comment: @Anixx, this assertion is simply not true. British constitutional history is fascinating on precisely this topic. Research the Glorious Revolution, Burke, the Regency Crisis, etc.

Comment: @Anixx, have you ever heard of the Magna Carta? The lords of England started curtailing the power of the British king over 800 years ago... The British monarch is nothing more then a figurehead today.

Comment: @Annix Edward VIII abdicated because his intended wife was unacceptable as Queen Consort - he may not have actually been deposed, but it was pretty close! No revolution, just a smooth(ish) transition to the heir presumptive, George VI.

Answer (score 5):

Chile has a long tradition of democracy and by 1941 already had 100 years of democracy, albeit with brief interludes. In 1941 Pedro Aguirre Cerda was president of Chile, elected in 1938. He died at the end of 1941 and was replaced by Jeónimo Mendez until April 1942, when Juan Antonio Rios won the election.
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Presidents_of_Chile

Answer (score -1):

Ireland (1936)... I don’t want to open a can of worms but there are good arguments for that to read any of the following

Parliamentary Democracy:
Ireland (1922)
Ireland (1937)
(One could also argue that it transitioned in 1949)

Constitutional Monarchy:
Ireland (1922)
Ireland (1936)
Ireland (1937)

It depends how you define constitutional monarchy. Ireland was definitely one in 1922 (or at least was the same as U.K. and Canada). 
In 1936 a new constitution was established, which transferred some powers of the King (delegated to the Governor General) to the new President (effective 1937) However the King remained head of state officially (particularly when it came to foreign affairs and diplomatic relations) and Ireland remained in the Commonwealth.

The Republic of Ireland Act 1948 made Ireland a republic and removed any remaining powers of the King (automatically leaving the Commonwealth). At that point, Ireland was (and remains) a parliamentary democracy with an elected President as head of state (similar to Italy and Germany today) and with the president as the guardian of the constitution.

Comment: Welcome to History SE. Sources would improve this answer and increase the likelihood of people responding positively to your post.

Comment: I'm not sure that this actually answers the question that was asked - it appears to be an extended comment about the state of Ireland.